# Perhaps The Back Room and The Game Table are confusingly named

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

While I do love the name of my room, Going to "the Back Room" for gaming and "The Game Table" for talking does seem slightly counterintuitive: every so often someone comes by the room and we have to steer him over to The Game Table.

While this certainly isn't a huge problem, suggestions for fixing it?

Comment: I have renamed them RPG General and Open Gaming.

Comment: this too drove me bonkers. thanks @mxyzplk.

Answer (score 4):

I was very confused by those names my first few times in chat...

I agree that "The Game Table" should be for gaming, and propose "Out of Character" for the chatty room.

Answer (score 4):

I agree.  I think cutesy names are always going to have that problem.  "General Discussion" and "Open Gaming" aren't cute but they help people know what's up. Naming discussion something like OOC is going to make people think that it's OOC discussion for an actual gaming chat, which is how that is used on every PBP forum in the universe.

Comment: +1. We also can't assume everyone is bringing with them the language and cultural context necessary to correctly interpret cutesy names.

Answer (score 3):

I like the name "Back Room" for the gaming section.  That is where we play games in most shops after all. :)

To keep the metaphor though, the talky room should be called, "The Front Counter"

We should change the room descriptions. Currently they are quite wordy.  Something like "Start here" and "Play games here" would be better.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the names as they stand are confusing. What about "The Tavern" for the chatty room?

Comment: Perhaps "Smoky Old Tavern with Mysterious Stranger?" for the chatty room?

Comment: If you think a longer name will draw people better, sure.

Answer (score 1):

How about Out of Character or OOC for the main room?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this recently.  We could certainly swap names, but I think the main problem is what do we name the "main" or "talky" room?

The name "Back Room" doesn't really work, and "Front Room" doesn't mean much either ...

RolePlayer's Lounge?

Someone has to have better suggestions.